# Separate JPlayer's Playlist From The Player To Enable Scrolling For Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jplayer, iscroll

I am looking for a way to separate the playlist (#jp_container_1) in the default jQuery Jplayer music player from the actual player portion (#jquery_jplayer_1) at the top. My goal is to enable iScroll to work within the playlist.

Here is a demo of the project I am working on where you can see the player and the two playlists on the audio tab. **http://sharethewub.com/mobile/**
I would like to integrate the default jplayer playlist into the iScroll playlist that I have listed underneath jplayer.

I attempted to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAuZ7/4/) of this project but I had issues getting the tabs to work there.

```
<div id="audio" style="position:absolute;top:9999px;overflow:hidden">
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">  
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1">unmute</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
      </div>
       <div id="jp_playlist_1" class="jp-playlist">
         <ul>
         </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Any insight into how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you just want to be able to move the playlist element:

```
<div id="jp_playlist_1" class="jp-playlist">
     <ul>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

outside of the #jquery_jplayer_1 container without breaking it's functionality. To do that you could simply edit the selector definition in jplayer.playlist.js. In **line 58** you can see the playlist selector being defined as

```
this.cssSelector.playlist = this.cssSelector.cssSelectorAncestor + " .jp-playlist";
```

which forces it to be a child of your main "cssSelector". If you only have one single player on your site you could simply change it to

```
this.cssSelector.playlist = " .jp-playlist";
```

I have not tried this but it should work!

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am trying to do and exactly what I needed, but I am finding that when I try to remove the original #jquery_jplayer_1 Div it breaks the player. Even removing the .jp-player class from the #jquery_jplayer_1 Div breaks it. So I'm still trying to remove the original playlist from the player so that the new scrolling list can be seen. I'll update the ShareTheWub.com/mobile/ and the jsfiddle soon. Thanks for your help! You've already helped me a ton.